# Spring data load failing with an Illegal state exception "Could not load JDBC driver class" in IntellIj

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am using the spring function to fetch values from the databse. I have added ojdbc6.jar to my external libraries under java folder.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="<<url>>" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

while running the program, I m getting the java illegal state exception, could not load the JDBC driver class.

In my build.gralde while mentioning the ojdbc jar, I am getting jar not found exception while building the dependents itself.

`compile com.oracle.ojdbc14:10.2.0.3.0`

IDE used: IntelliJ

Edited: But when I use the following code in a java class, it is working fine without any error

`class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`